# Why can't I check whether my class implements my own interface at Web Application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, reflection

I'm trying to write something like framework. I need to search particular folder on my computer and be able to get all class files that are there which implements my interface. While I know how to scan folder and check all class files somehow I can't get to check whether read class implements my interface.

```
if (Game.class.isAssignableFrom(classInFolder))
    {
        //Do sth here
}
```

That's one approach I tried but it never hop into if clause - Game is my Interface

```
public interface Game {

public void startAlgorithm();

}
```

and classInFolder is Class that I got from my folder. Funny thing if I try to do the same with some library interface - let's say Serializable it works fine - I tried it. What's more when I wrote something like that

```
Type[] type = classInFolder.getGenericInterfaces();
for (int i = 0;i<type.length;++i)
{
    System.out.println("interface = " + type[i]);
    if (type[i] instanceof Game){
    System.out.println("It is");
    }
}
```

I got on my console output -  interface = mypackage.Game
But there was not "It is" output. The same thing was with my own annotation on class I tried to use - I can't get to check whether my class implements my interfaces but it works when those are interfaces from some lib. I deploy my project on tomcat v 7.0 everything is build on Java 7 on Eclipse with the use of Spring.

I would be grateful for any ideas about what could be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Game` class is probably loaded by tomcat class loader.

Your `classInFolder` is probably loaded by your own custom class loader.

You need to make sure that the 1st loader is the parent of the 2nd loader

```
ClassLoader parent = Game.class.getClassLoader();

new MyClassLoader(parent, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you load your classes with different `ClassLoader`s. A class loaded by one class loader isn't the same as the same class loaded with a different class loader.

Try loading it with the same `ClassLoader`.

---

```
Object a1 = new ClassLoader() {}.loadClass("A");
Object a2 = new ClassLoader() {}.loadClass("A");

return a1.getClass().equals(a2.getClass());
```

will return `false`.

Comment: Tha's what it was about and below is how to resolve it. Thanks to both of You.

Answer (score 2):

There is not "It is" output in your example because you should use an instance of the desired class to the left of the instanceof operator, while you are using a Type instance there.

Try using [Class.getInterfaces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29) to get the interfaces implemented by a class and look for your interface in the array returned by the getInterfaces() method.

Answer (score 2):

Using `instanceof` operator, **you are checking the object instance not the interface.**

To check the interface, try getting the interfaces as there could be more than one, iterate the list and match the type as below:

```
        for (Class ifce : type[i].getClass().getInterfaces()) {
           if (ifce.equals(Game.class)) {
                System.out.println("It is");
           }
         }
```

Comment: well that's basically what i said, but it's right nonetheless. :)

Comment: @AlexandruMihai: I opened the question earlier and was inactive so didn't see your answer. I will vote for you :)